# filter text column by its equivalent date value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two column in database named `id int(11)` and `month_year varchar(255)` respectively.
in table I have following records,

```
id month_year
1  01_2013 
2  06_2013 
3  09_2013 
4  03_2014
5  09_2014
```

I want financial 2013-14 records i.e In 2013 month starts from April(04) and In 2014 from March(03).
So, my result should look like.

```
id month_year
2  06_2013 
3  09_2013 
4  03_2014
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/442e70

Comment: Why not store dates using a date data type? 2013-01-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select * from Table1 
where concat(right(month_year,4),left(month_year,2)) between '201304' and '201403'
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/442e70/3).